# When is Gibraltar expected to become part of the Schengen area?

Tags: schengen, gibraltar

Maybe this is a how long is a piece of string question but does anyone have any idea?

AFAIK, there is not currently any limit on how long a British citizen can stay in Gibraltar (Wikipedia says all British citizens have right of abode in Gibraltar but doesn't give a source; the UK government website just says that British citizens don't need a visa). I assume that once Gibraltar becomes part of the Schengen area the 90/180 rule will apply to British citizens just the same as it would to anyone else, but can anyone confirm?

Comment: This matter seems to have stalled, probably because of negotiation problems elsewhere. Since September there have been no public statements on this topic that I know of.

Comment: As far as I understand it, Gibraltar will not join the Schengen Area, it will have a similar status but not exactly the same. It is not clear that UK citizens would see their privileges in Gibraltar change (and I would actually doubt it). But until the final text is agreed on, nobody really knows…

Comment: In the absence of any other information, it can't be automatically assumed that Gibraltar joining the Schengen area would cause the 90/180 rule to apply inside Gibraltar: one possible scenario is that British citizens would be treated like residence permit holders and have 90/180 apply only outside of British territory.